# Calculate cumulative monthly and year value starting from given MTD and YTD

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following data:

```
Name  | Production_day | tonnes |  MTD  | YTD
------------------------------------------
 gas  | 06/Aug/17      | 2047   | 15000 | 48000 
 gas  | 07/Aug/17      | 1547   |       | 
 gas  | 08/Aug/17      | 1747   |       | 
 gas2 | 06/Aug/17      | 3047   | 15050 | 48800 
 gas2 | 07/Aug/17      | 5547   |       | 
 gas2 | 08/Aug/17      | 9747   |       |
```

I have given MTD and YTD and I need to calculate cumulative monthly and year tonnes value starting from given MTD and YTD.

Desired result so as example for gas, MTD=15000+1547, YTD=48000+1547 and etc:

```
Name  | Production_day | tonnes |  MTD  | YTD
------------------------------------------
 gas  | 06/Aug/17      | 2047   | 15000 | 48000 
 gas  | 07/Aug/17      | 1547   | 16547 | 49547
 gas  | 08/Aug/17      | 1747   | 18294 | 51294
 gas2 | 06/Aug/17      | 3047   | 15050 | 48800 
 gas2 | 07/Aug/17      | 5547   |       | 
 gas2 | 08/Aug/17      | 9747   |       |
```

I could easily do it with query below but how to tell to start calculating from given MTD and YTD?:

```
select name,PRODUCTION_DAY, tonnes, sum(tonnes) over (partition by name,  to_char(PRODUCTION_DAY, 'MON-YYYY') order by PRODUCTION_DAY ) MTD from  MV_D_MAS_LASTYEAR order by name, PRODUCTION_DAY
```

thanks,
S

Comment: Edit your question and show the desired results.

Comment: You should use group by statement

Answer (score 0):

Define the groups by using a cumulative sum.  Then use those groups for the cumulative sum:

```
select m.*,
       (sum(tonnes) over (partition by name, ytd_grp order by production_day) +
        max(ytd) over (partition by name, ytd_grp)
       ) as running_ytd,
       (sum(tonnes) over (partition by name, mtd_grp order by production_day) +
        max(mtd) over (partition by name, mtd_grp)
       ) as running_mtd
from (select m.*,
             sum(case when ytd is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by production_day) as ytd_grp,
             sum(case when mtd is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by production_day) as mtd_grp,
      from MV_D_MAS_LASTYEAR m
     ) m
order by name, PRODUCTION_DAY
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for response, it gives following error: [Error] Execution (55: 16): ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.  sum(case when ytd should be with group by function?

Comment: I used this one: select name, PRODUCTION_DAY, TONNES,
sum(MTD) over (partition by name, to_char(PRODUCTION_DAY, 'MON-YYYY') order by PRODUCTION_DAY ) MTD, 
sum(YTD) over (partition by name, to_char(PRODUCTION_DAY, 'YYYY') order by PRODUCTION_DAY ) YTD 
from 
(
select NAME,PRODUCTION_DAY,TONNES, TONNES MTD, TONNES YTD from MV_XHQ_DMAS_LAST6MONTH where NET_MASS_YTD_MTON is null 
union
select NAME,PRODUCTION_DAY,TONNES, NET_MASS_MTD_MTON,NET_MASS_YTD_MTON from MV_XHQ_DMAS_LAST6MONTH where NET_MASS_YTD_MTON is not null 
) 
order by name, PRODUCTION_DAY